# VS WPF Designer Change Control Gap Guide

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have searched through all the settings but cannot find if this is possible.
Changing the gap guide warning in wpf designer. See the red area.

[image]

The defaults are good but in most situations I need to move them without guide to fit nicely on the view. 
Designing would be a lot faster specially for a full-stack less designing-talent dude. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have VS 2012 installed anymore but even so, I do not see a way to do this in the Visual Studio 2015 designer nor 2017.

But... Blend does have options to adjust the spacing. Under Tools -> Options -> XAML Designer -> Artboard.